# name of object within payload javascript

Tags: javascript, vue.js, object-reference

I have this payload.

```
{name: "Sinto 6", val: {…}, line: "Sinto 6"}
line: "Sinto 6"
name: "Sinto 6"
val:
AvgMachTime: 253
AvgManTime: 1343
CollectMachTimer: 359
CollectManTimer: 108
CycleTimeMach: 359
CycleTimeMan: 140
FaultTime: 15297
MachTargetSeconds: 330
ManTargetSeconds: 95
NGPartCount: 63
OnHeatTime: 11201
PartCount: 12
PartTarget: 78
```

I'm trying to use Vue to set the values in the state using

```
const PERFORMANCE_COMMIT = (state, payload) => {
Vue.set(state["Performance"][payload.line], [payload.val], payload.val);
}
```

I realise one of my payload.val need to be the name of the value and not the name itself.

How can I reference this correctly?

My state looks like this:

```
Performance: {
    TotalPartTarget: 0,
    TotalPartCount: 0,
    Difference: 0,
    OEE: 0,
    OEETarget: 100,
    "Sinto 6" :{
      PartTarget: 0,
      PartCount: 0,
      NGPartCount: 0,
      OEE: 0,
      FaultTime: 0,
      OnHeatTime: 0,
      CycleTimeMan: 0,
      CycleTimeMach: 0,
      CollectManTimer: 0,
      CollectMachTimer: 0,
      AvgManTime: 0,
      AvgMachTime: 0,
      ManTargetSeconds: 0,
      MachTargetSeconds: 0
```

Edit: Spelling

Comment: how does the state look like?

Comment: Added state to main post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the Vue documentation ([Vue.set Documentation Link](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#Vue-set)), first parameter is target, second is property name / index and third is the value.

So, in you case target property is **state["Performance"]**, property name is **payload.line ("Sinto 6")** and value is **payload.val**.

```
const PERFORMANCE_COMMIT = (state, payload) => {
  Vue.set(state["Performance"], payload.line, payload.val);
}
```